# how to extract all digit in nvarchar variable in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanna extract all digit in nvarchar variable and store them in a table or pre-declare variable.
example:

```
declare @natioanlCode nvarchar(10) = '0083441141';
```

and the target result may be like this.

```
declare @n1 int = 0;
declare @n2 int = 0;
declare @n3 int = 8;
declare @n4 int = 3;
declare @n5 int = 4;
declare @n6 int = 4;
declare @n7 int = 1;
declare @n8 int = 1;
declare @n9 int = 4;
declare @n10 int = 1;
```

Comment: What's wrong with `SUBSTRING`?

Comment: Why would you want to this?

Comment: @Larnu nothing except I'm looking for creative solution.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I'm trying check eqaulity of sum of them to specific number in that string

Comment: *"I'm looking for creative solution"* What does that even mean..? Most odd method to achieve a simple task? Why? Just use `SUBSTRING`.

Comment: Yet another https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz
cool, I'm just ask. If you dont know wait until a creative answer will be found

Comment: Funny. https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/82/sql?userid=6336479

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implemetation of the recursive cte from the answer of @SalmanA but this time without substring since you don't seem to like that

```
with test as (
    select N'0083441141' as str 
), rcte as (
    select value = left(str, 1), 
           leftover = right(str, len(str) - 1)
    from test

    union all

    select left(leftover, 1),
           right(leftover, len(leftover) - 1) 
    from rcte
    where len(leftover) > 0
)
select value
from rcte
```

See also this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a4cb61045c0aa67f2309b44a630f2e3)

You can also insert this result into an existing table if you want, see this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e33443b11afd5d8914dfd1e8cf2426d) for an example

Comment: Isn't this answer, including faux column names, a ditto copy of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72647386/87015

Comment: @SalmanA That is why the answer starts with "Another implementation of a recursive cte, but this time without substring" Yes, it is the same answer but I just replaced the substring with left and right, because the OP did not wanted to use the substring. This was not meant to steal your answer, I am sorry if I offended you

Comment: @SalmanA I edited my answer to reflect that I based it on you answer, I should have done that right away as I realize now, once again, sorry

Answer (score 0):

With no explanation, I can only assume "creative" means many lines of code, possibly inefficient, and difficult to understand. One such solution would be something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @natioanlCode nvarchar(10) = '0083441141';

CREATE TABLE #temp (ID int IDENTITY,
                    I int)
DECLARE @C char(1);
WHILE LEN(@natioanlCode) > 0 BEGIN
    SET @C = LEFT(@natioanlCode,1);
    SET @natioanlCode = STUFF(@natioanlCode,1,1,'');

    IF @C LIKE '[0-9]'
        INSERT INTO #temp (I)
        VALUES(@C)
    ELSE
        PRINT CONCAT(@C, N' isn''t a number');
END;

SELECT I
FROM #temp
ORDER BY ID;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Of course, the easiest way would be to use `SUBSTRING`, but this isn't "creative" (but far more performant):

```
DECLARE @natioanlCode nvarchar(10) = '0083441141';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@natioanlCode,V.I,1)
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))V(I)
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(@natioanlCode,V.I,1))
ORDER BY V.I;
```